# Django Rest: Retrieving by a different parameter using ModelViewSet

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

How can I retrieve a user by username rather than the primary key while using the rest frameworks `ModelViewSet`?

Here is my current view:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    lookup_field = 'username'
```

If you want to use object lookups other than pk, set `'lookup_field'`.

Comment: Perfect, do you also happen to know how to lookup using e-mails? It seems like the @ symbol causes problems when it's passed as a parameter, always returning 'Not Found'.

Comment: @ symbol will not causes problems,please update your question